# Scan Wifi Network using Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking, wifi

Could someone tell me (or an example) on how to scan/connect in a wifi network using Visual Basic ? (VB.NET 2010)

I've google it but didn't found anything useful.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/). It is a wrapper around the native Wifi API, making it simpler to interact with.

Answer (score -1):

This will only displaying output in messagebox This isn't what you looking for but it give you a idea.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnScan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnScan.Click
        Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh"
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show networks mode=bssid"
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        proc.Start()
        MsgBox(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
    End Sub
End Class
```